# No binding operation info exception

Tags: c#, java, web-services, jakarta-ee, cxf

i created a CXF web service with SOAP 1.2

when a client (C#) calls it, it throws a warnning, complain no binding operation info.

do i need to do something in my code???

```
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public interface IDartProxy {

    String run(@WebParam(name = "s") String s);
}



import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.mydemo.demo.IDartProxy")
public class DartProxyImpl implements IDartProxy {

    @Override
    public String run(String s) {
        return "Hello " + s;
    }
}



<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
        xmlns:soap="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
                            http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

    <jaxws:endpoint
      id="dartProxy"
      implementor="com.mydemo.demo.DartProxyImpl"
      address="/DartProxy"
          >
        <jaxws:binding>
            <soap:soapBinding mtomEnabled="true" version="1.2"/>
        </jaxws:binding>
        <jaxws:features>
            <wsa:addressing xmlns:wsa="http://cxf.apache.org/ws/addressing"/>
        </jaxws:features>
    </jaxws:endpoint>
</beans>
```

Exception:

```
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://demo.mydemo.com/}DartProxyImplService has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No binding operation info while invoking unknown method with params unknown.
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:60)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:255)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:113)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:97)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:461)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:188)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:148)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:179)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:103)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:159)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:502)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:389)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:417)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:535)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:880)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:747)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:520)
16/12/2010 10:00:16 PM org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker invoke
SEVERE: Invocation without a binding operation.
16/12/2010 10:00:16 PM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://demo.mydemo.com/}DartProxyImplService has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No binding operation info while invoking unknown method with params unknown.
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:60)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:255)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:113)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:97)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:461)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:188)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:148)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:179)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:103)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:159)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:502)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:389)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:417)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:535)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:880)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:747)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:520)
```

Comment: I have the same problem.please you how fixed!  
 are you tell me to my email  dong_an@foxmail.com

 thank you

Comment: If you have a problem ask it in a new question. Answers are only for providing solutions.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot

```
@WebMethod
```

It should be

```
@WebService(name = "yourServiceSOAP", targetNamespace = "/namespace")
@javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public interface AssignmentAccountService {

     @WebMethod  
    String run(@WebParam(name = "s") String s);

}
```

Comment: @shrimpy Check update interface should look like this, implementation is  ok